# Want to display error message on label in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display error message in label on click if the textbox is empty or undefined using AngularJS.

I am very beginner into AngularJS.

Please help to solve this issue.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="form">
    <div ng-controller="formController">
        <label>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /></label><br />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
        <pre>{{master | json}}</pre>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module('form', []).controller('formController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.master = {};
                $scope.update = function (user) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
                    if (user == undefined) {
                        debugger;
                        alert("Please enter text");
                    }
                };
            }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it will never be undefined or empty, sicne you are using ng-model

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Please show me the solution. If there is no data entered into textbox then it should display error message in a label.please help me. I am new to AngularJS so do not have much ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body>

<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="Validate()">

<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>

<span ng-show="ShowUserNameError">Username is required.</span>
</span>
</p>
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" ng-click="Validate()">
</p>

</form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.ShowUserNameError = false;
    $scope.user = '';
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.Validate = function(){   
    if(!$scope.user)
    $scope.ShowUserNameError = true;
    else
     $scope.ShowUserNameError = false;
     
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please add if user types anything in textbox, it should display in a label like you have done for error message. Please help!

Comment: just use like following
 <label ng-show="ShowUserNameError">Username is required:</label>

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the input in a named form, name the input, and use `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-controller="formController">
  <form name="form1">
    <label>Name: <span ng-show="form1.item1.$error">{{form1.item1.$error}}</span>
       <input name="item1" type="text" required ng-model="user.name" />
    </label><br />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
         <pre>{{master | json}}</pre>
   </form>
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<form>` Directive API Reference - Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#examples)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)